# Conditions for a map to be $\mathbb{R}$-linear

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a map $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, is the condition that for all $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ enough for $f$ to be $\mathbb{R}$-linear? I cannot prove it or think of a counter example.

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385586/do-there-exist-functions-satisfying-fxy-fxfy-that-arent-linear) should give you an answer for the case where $m=n=1$

Answer (score -1):

It should also satisfy:

$$f(ax)=af(x).$$